# How to tell gulp-connect to open index.html regardless of the URL?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: __dirname,
    livereload: true
  });
});
```

and the following Angular routes:

```
angular.module("MyApp", ["ngRoute"]).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      controller: "DashboardCtrl",
      templateUrl: "templates/dashboard.html"
    })
    .when("/advertiser", {
      controller: "AdvertiserCtrl",
      templateUrl: "templates/advertiser.html"
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/"
    });
});
```

When I visit `/` all works fine (the Dashboard appears).

But, visiting `/advertiser` results in "404 - Cannot GET /advertiser".

My main Angular file is `index.html`, which is opened properly for `/`, but not for `/advertiser`.

How could I tell Gulp to open `index.html` regardless of the URL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `middleware` option to use [the `connect-history-api-fallback` middleware](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback).  Once you've installed and required the fallback, you add it like this:

```
gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: __dirname,
    livereload: true,

    middleware: function(connect, opt) {
      return [ historyApiFallback ];
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I need. See also: https://github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/issues/48

Comment: Just a note for everyone that finds this issue. On newer versions of `connect-history-api-fallback` you'll have to call `historyApiFallback()` as a function.

See this [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for more information.

Answer (score 47):

Alternatively you can use `gulp-connect` own option called `fallback` for that:

```
gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: 'path/',
    livereload: true,
    fallback: 'path/index.html'
  });
});
```

No need for another package.

Comment: That's the answer to take! No need to download another package. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i was looking for

Comment: I have been searching for a solution to this for a day or two now. Thanks, this is perfect!

Comment: This actually causes the file to become the 404 document which is not always ideal.

Comment: works.. but dont forget to replace 'path/' with your actual root.. fallback need full path relative to gulp file.

Comment: this doesn't work always due to content-security-policy issues

Comment: This should be the answer!