# How to tell gulp-connect to use a specific base URL?

Tags: javascript, http, url, web, gulp-connect

Can I tell gulp-connect to use a specific base URL that does not relate to the folder structure it is serving from? 
I am trying to serve the app directly from the src folder and therefor set gulp-connect's root to 'src'. The src folder contains the index.html.
When I browse to "localhost:< port >". It shows the index.html, but because of internal use of a JavaScriptvariable set to the production base URL, the internal routing and script loading does not work. That's why I want to tell gulp-connect, to behave as If the production base URL would be left out.

For example: Browsing to 'localhost:8080/MyApp/index.html' should basically do the same as browsing to 'localhost:8080/index.html'.

Comment: Can this post help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013353/how-to-tell-gulp-connect-to-open-index-html-regardless-of-the-url?

Comment: I had this one already open, but It seems not solve my problem as I don't want a fallback option to point to a specific site rather than to get all paths working as If they where moved inside a folder named like the specified base URL. Using a fallback like this does not get rid of problems with the internal calls that load additional scripts for example...